# Let only select specific cells with shouldSelectItemAt indexPath function

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, indexpath

I want that only four specific cells can be selected at one time. When a button is pressed, I want that the selectable cells are 4 `indexPath.row` lower.

Example: In the beginning, `indexPath.row` 44-47 is selectable. If the button is pressed I want, that the `indexPath.row` 40-43 is selectable and so on.

I thought about making an array with the indexPath and If the button is pressed, the numbers in the array are 4 numbers lower.

Than I don't know, how to add this to the `shouldSelectItemAt indexPath` function.

How can I realize this?

Comment: Are you keeping the selected indices (such as 44-47) in an Int array?

Comment: That was my idea :)

Comment: What about using a `(NS)(Mutable)IndexSet` if you use only one section. Add the "allowed" or "disabled" (I don't know which one you want) to be selectable/unselectable.

Comment: @Larme What is that? I'm very new on this topic so I don't know many different ways to solve a problem

Comment: One doubt: You are mentioning `indexPath.row`, and `shouldSelectItemAt`. `row` is to be used for **UITableView** (`item` for **UICollectionView**) and `shouldSelectItemAt` is for UICollectionView. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using UICollectionView and shouldSelectItemAt

Comment: I've added an answer with the logic for decrementing the range and handling the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [IndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset).

```
var allowedSelectionRow: IndexSet
allowedSelectionRow.insert(integersIn: 44...47) //Initial allowed selection rows
```

In `collectionView(_:shouldSelectItemAt:)`

```
return allowedSelectionRow.contains(indexPath.row) //or indexPath.item
```

Whenever you need:

```
allowedSelectionRow.remove(integersIn: 44...47) //Remove indices from 44 to 47
allowedSelectionRow.insert(integersIn: 40...43) //Add indices from 40 to 43
```

Advantage from an Array: Like a set, there is unicity of the values (no duplicates). Contains only integers, and you can add in "range" which can be useful (not add all the indices, but a range).

After comments, if you have only 4 rows allowed and consecutive, you can have that method:

```
func updateAllowedSectionSet(lowerBound: Int) { 
    let newRange = lowerBound...(lowerBound+3)
    allowedSectionRow.removeAll() //Call remove(integersIn:) in case for instance that you want always the 1 row to be selectable for instance
    allowedSectionRow.insert(integersIn: newRange) 
}
```

For the first one, you just need to do:
`updateAllowedSectionSet(lowerBound: 44)` instead of `allowedSelectionRow.insert(integersIn: 44...47)`

Comment: Thanks man! That worked as far as I wanted it to work. One little question: Is it possible to automate the process with the remove and insert? E.g. the first number always 4 lower and the last as well??

Comment: You can create a function for that: `func update(withLowerBound: Int)` , when you give only the lower bound: it does the removal (note that you can use `removeAll()` instead of removing at specific indices), it create the range from the lower bound, and does the insert on that range.

Comment: `func updateAllowedSectionSet(lowerBound: Int) { let newRange = lowerBound...(lowerBound+3); allowedSectionRow.removeAll(); allowedSectionRow.insert(integersIn: newRange) }`, or something like that (didn't check the bounds). And so you do `self.updateAllowedSectionSet(lowerBound: 44)` (for the first one). Note: You can completely replace the whole `allowedSelectionRow` with the new one. I suggested previously `remove()` because you might want to keep for instance always the first row selectable (or something like that).

Comment: Perfect :D The world needs more heroes like you :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider that the items form a String array, and you are keeping track of the selected indices as a Range.

```
var selectedRange: Range<Int>? {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

var items: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        // To make sure that the selected indices are reset everytime this array is modified,
        // so as to make sure that nothing else breaks
        if items.count >= 4 {
            // Select the last 4 items by default
            selectedRange = (items.count - 4)..<items.count
        } else if !items.isEmpty {
            selectedRange = 0..<items.count
        } else {
            selectedRange = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you are pressing the button to decrement the range, you can use this logic to handle the same:

```
func decrementRange() {
    if var startIndex = selectedRange?.startIndex,
        var endIndex = selectedRange?.endIndex {

        startIndex = max((startIndex - 4), 0)
        endIndex = min(max((startIndex + 4), (endIndex - 4)), items.count)

        selectedRange = startIndex..<endIndex
    }
}
```

Then, you can identify whether the the selection is being done on the active range using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    if let selectedRange = selectedRange {
        return selectedRange.contains(indexPath.item)
    }
    return false
}
```

**Note**: I would advice you to verify whether this covers all the corner cases before trying it out for production code.